# Why all the python compilers cannot recognize PyQt5 module?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I download the PyQt5 module with the 'pip install PyQt5' cmd command. The it shows that the installation was successful, but when I try to import the module to an editor,e.x. Visual Studio or Sublime, it says that there is no document with that name. How can I fix that?

Comment: if you say cmd command i will suppose that you are doing that on windows. by "import the module to an editor" what are doing, editing the source of the module? loading in interpreter the module (in which case why do you need an editor)?

Comment: I am writing a program for a project that our professor gave us and we need the PyQt5 module. I installed it and i wrote 'import PyQt5' at the beginning of my code. When i tried to run the program, i got a ModuleNotFoundError. But when i tried to install it again from the cmd, it said that the module was already installed. Do you have any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: do you have multiple version of python installed?

Comment: Yes i have versions 3.9 and 3.10

Comment: pip only install for one of these version and probably the wrong one. verify that the version you have installed the library for and the one you are trying to import the library from are the same